# How to print a variable into a tkinter label on python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The following are two lists which hold item details extracted from Amazon's website.

```
price_audible = ['$1.99', '$1.50', '$1.00', '$1.99', '$1.50', '$1.00', '$1.99', '$1.50', '$1.00', '$1.99']
description_audible = ['A', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
newlist = []
for m in range(0, 10):
    '\n'
        var_1=('#'+description_audible[m])+ '\n' +('('+price_audible[m]+')')+'\n'
        newlist.append(var_1)
        print(*newlist)
    b = print(*newlist)

    dash_1 = Tk()
    dash_1.configure(bg = 'red')
    dash_1.title("Amazon Bestsellers Audible")
    Label(dash_1, text = "Amazon Bestsellers Audible", font = ('Arial', 14),
    bg='red', fg='floralwhite').pack()
    Label(dash_1, text = b).pack()
    dash_1.mainloop()
```

I want to print the variable b to a tkinter label. When I run the code it just prints the variable b in a shell window. I want it to be printed on the label.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `textvariable` attribute to set the text in a label based on a variable.

```
b = StringVar()
b.set(*newlist)
...
Label(dash_1, textvariable = b).pack()
```

Comment: Hi Ross, I tried it but it gives me the following error.  But it only works for 1 items it can print 1 item not 10. Is there a way to fix this?                                                                                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shara\Desktop\Assignmentttttt.py", line 61, in <module>
    b.set(*newlist)
TypeError: set() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: I think that is because you have an array. Try replacing this line      `newlist.append(var_1)` with `newlist = newlist + var_1` and `newlist = []` with `newlist = ""`

Comment: Hey Ross can you please help me with my recent question on here. Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549363/how-to-use-spinbox-for-selection-of-items-in-a-list-and-then-using-add-to-cart-b